# Empty SOAP response in SOAPUI, Postman

Tags: node.js, soap, wsdl

I have trouble receiving a response from a SOAP request. The response is empty. If I query using the HelloWorld service, I receive the expected response and I can parse it -> HelloWorld. However, if I query another service, I do receive status 200, everything looks okay, except the response which is empty. Here is the code:

```
POST
'user-agent': 'portjust',
'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8',
'SOAPAction': 'portalquery.just.ro/CautareDosare'

URL: 'http://portalquery.just.ro/Query.asmx?op=CautareDosare'

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <CautareDosare xmlns="portalquery.just.ro">
      <numarDosar>string</numarDosar> // can be empty
      <obiectDosar>string</obiectDosar> // can be empty
      <numeParte>mihaela</numeParte>
      <institutie>JudecatoriaARAD</institutie>
      <dataStart>2021-06-23T15:52:46.031Z</dataStart>
      <dataStop>2016-06-23T15:52:46.031Z</dataStop>
    </CautareDosare>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

And the response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
       <CautareDosareResponse xmlns="portalquery.just.ro" />
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The results are the same in SOAPui, postman, and NODEJS(easy-soap-request)

WSDL: http://portalquery.just.ro/Query.asmx?WSDL
Hello World Example: http://portalquery.just.ro/query.asmx?op=HelloWorld

Official example cautare Dosare: http://portalquery.just.ro/Query.asmx?op=CautareDosare

With respect,

Andrei

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit. Datetime format must be ISO 8601 with time (T) set to 00:00:00.000Z. Everything works okay now.